# call void on showing the view

Tags: iphone, view, initialization

is there something that can call a -(void) every time a view shows. 
I am rotating between two views, so when i go to the second view and then return to the first view I want a void to be called automatically from the first view
I've try to do this with -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated and - (void)viewDidLoad
by putting a NSLog in them but it doesn't print when i return to the first view. 
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are updating the first view with data from the second, use an observer on the model that is being updated.  If the second view is being removed as a subview, you can observe the subviews.  Alternatively, you can use a block callback closure.

In the interface:

```
IBAction(^doOnClose)(void);
```

and:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) IBAction(^doOnClose)(void);
```

In the method that closes your second view:

```
if(doOnClose) doOnClose();
```

And finally to define it from your first view:

```
view2.doOnClose = ^{/*Do this when view 2 closes*/};
```

Comment: I didn't really got what you are suggesting so please elaborate if you can. here is my code

Answer (score 0):

I have two methods in the app delegate

```
-(void)goTo1{ 

 [self.window addSubview:[viewController view]]; 
 [settingsViewController.view removeFromSuperview];


 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
  //removing the settingsViewController form the view and setting the animation
  [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:window cache:NO];

  [UIView commitAnimations];
  [settingsViewController release];
  settingsViewController = nil; }
```

and

```
-(void)goTo2{

 //calling the .xib file and the SettingsViewController
 SettingsViewController *aSettingsView = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Settings" bundle:nil];
 [self setSettingsViewController:aSettingsView];
 [aSettingsView release];

 [self.window addSubview:[settingsViewController view]];
 //moving the view 30px down
 [[settingsViewController view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460)];

 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
 //setting the animation
 [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:window cache:YES];

 [UIView commitAnimations]; 
 [webskiAppBetaViewController release];
 webskiAppBetaViewController = nil;
}
```

and IBActions in the 2 view controllers
first One

```
-(IBAction)goToView2{

 WebskiAppBetaAppDelegate *mainDelegate = (WebskiAppBetaAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 [mainDelegate goTo2]; 
}
```

and second one

```
-(IBAction)goToView1{
 WebskiAppBetaAppDelegate *maniDelegate = (WebskiAppBetaAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 [maniDelegate goTo1];
}
```

so now when i call goToVIew1 I also want to run a method that is in the view 1

something like this

```
-(IBAction)goToView1{

 WebskiAppBetaAppDelegate *maniDelegate = (WebskiAppBetaAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 [maniDelegate goTo1];
[self methodInFirstVIew]; //this method is in the first view
}
```